# How to do google sheet filtering? Group Data of One Column To one Cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ9j9EuHnvBPi_IYhheTbttwG-D5JHYcSGodSl3eSydEG1z5R7PFfKAOw6G-XrNEZQnxvDg_-5PmgDp/pubhtml

**I have a google sheet like the above link it looks like this**

```
Timestamp   Exact   Username of Hacker  Video Link
6/30/2020 1:55:21   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 1:59:09   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 1:59:14   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 1:59:19   Column1DummyData    
6/30/2020 2:59:31   Svd 
6/30/2020 2:59:37   Svd 
6/30/2020 10:38:15  qwerty  
6/30/2020 10:44:15  test                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UZzu4UQLcI 
6/30/2020 10:58:53  test                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbgzrKJvDRw
6/30/2020 10:59:33  test                https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxpX_mubz2A
```

**I managed to make an output like this using the query:**

```
=QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''")
```

---

```
Name               NumberOfItem 

Column1DummyData         4

Svd                      2

qwerty                   1

test                     3
```

**But I Need an output Like this**

```
Name               NumberOfItem    Video link

Column1DummyData         4

Svd                      2

qwerty                   1

test                     3         https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UZzu4UQLcI, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbgzrKJvDRw, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxpX_mubz2A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), {
 QUERY(B2:C, "select B,count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B label count(B)''"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(
 QUERY(B2:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "offset 1", 0)="",,QUERY(
 QUERY(B2:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "limit 0", 1)&",")),,99^99))), ",$", )}, 3, 0))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Small help... Can you please add Sorting to Number of Items column in descending order

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(B2:B, "select B,count(B) where B !='' group by B label count(B)''"), {
 QUERY(B2:C, "select B,count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B label count(B)''"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(
 QUERY(B2:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "offset 1", 0)="",,QUERY(
 QUERY(B2:C, "select count(B) where B !='' and C !='' group by B pivot C"), 
 "limit 0", 1)&",")),,99^99))), ",$", )}, 3, 0))}, "order by Col2 desc", 0))`